# $A^T A = AA^T$ implies $|Av| = |A^T v|$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

> Let $A$ be a matrix with real coefficients and assume $A^T A = AA^T$. Prove that $|Av| = |A^T v|$.

I cannot figure out how to get started or how to use the equality. I'm not able to "cancel" $A$ or $A^T$ from either side, and because the matrix is arbitrary, I can't write out a brute-force proof from the entries.

Comment: Prove $$(Av)\cdot (Av)=|Av|^2=|A^Tv|^2=(A^Tv)\cdot (A^Tv)$$ using that $u\cdot (Aw)=(A^Tu)\cdot w.$

Answer (score 0):

I think $|Av|$ is actually $||Av||$. (Cause for higher dimensions($\gt 1$) case , modulus isn't the right indication.)

If we use the corresponding inner product (taking in usual sense) ,
Then ,
$||Av||^{2}$
$= < Av, Av>$
$= <A^{t}Av,v>$
$=<AA^{t}v,v>$
$=<A^{t}v,A^{t}v>$
$=||A^{t}v||^{2}$

Comment: The notation $|v|$ is usually used for the Euclidian norm of vectors (so $|v|^2 = v\cdot v = \sum_j v_j^2$) which allows to use $\|\cdot\|$ for all the other more complicated norms. For example in analysis, $\langle f,f\rangle =\|f\|$ is more used for functions spaces. Another case actually where it is used actually is for the abosolute value of an operator $|A| = \sqrt{A^*A}$ (which is the generalization of the vector case). By the way, the commands for the scalar product brackets are \langle and \rangle

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Vert w \Vert$ be interpreted as a length of vector $ w $ so it is non-negative number obtained from $\sqrt {w^Tw }$.

Now we can compare $(Av)^T(Av)$ and $(A^Tv)^T(A^Tv)$.

We use general formula for transposition of a product $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$